# Android setColor - want to change color but always didn't work

Tags: android, colors, drawing, paint

I want to change color to used in the following example to brown, but my attempts are not working:

```
 mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
 mPaint.setDither(true);
 mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

This doesn't work:

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.Brown);
```

nor does this:

```
mPaint.setColor(mPaint.setColor(0x00994C00));
```

It only works when I change the color to to `RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE`, `CYAN`, `MAGENTA`.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: How does it fail if you do `mPaint.setColor(0x00994C00);`? That looks like it should work.

Comment: there is on such thing `Color.Brown`, also 0x00994C00 is the same as 0x00000000 (Color.TRANSPARENT)

Comment: @MarcinKoziński mPaint.setColor(0x00994C00) is the same as mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) since the alpha component is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(0xff, 0x99, 0x4c, 0x00));
```

or:

```
mPaint.setColor(0xff994c00);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int myColor= getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(com.package_name.R.color.white);
mPaint.setColor(myColor);
```

define white color in your color.xml file